# SQL Server 2008 While Loop & Union data sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, while-loop, union-all

I've been able to successfully loop through a calculation query, but I want all the data to populate in 1 data set instead of multiple data sets. I can't seem to find a way to add some sort of UNION ALL to the loop (dsnt seem to play nice with the While Loop).  My goal in this looped calculation is to get Year to Date Totals as they stand for each day in the year (ex. 1/1/2014-1/2/2014, 1/1/2014-1/3/2014...all the way out to current 1/1/2014-9/15/2014.) Looping seems to be the only way to accomplish this without having 365 calculation blocks in the query (1 for each day of the year.)  Any help regarding this would be much appreciated!

```
DECLARE @Lcounter INT
SET @Lcounter = 0

WHILE (@StartDte + @Lcounter < GetDate ( ))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        YEAR(ACD.WorkDte) as WorkDte, 
        @StartDte + @Lcounter as RptType, 
        'Month' as RptLvl,
        ACD.LOB, 'NULL' as CIB, 'NULL' as SwitchNbr, 
        'NULL' as SkillNbr,  
        (SUM(ACD.ACDCallTotCt) + SUM(ACD.AbandonCallTotCt) - SUM(ACD.AbandonCall1Ct) )as CallsRcvd, 
        SUM(ACD.ACDCallTotCt) as CallsAnswrd
    FROM 
        #FinalResults ACD 
    WHERE 
        ACD.WorkDte >= @StartDte 
        AND ACD.WorkDte <= @StartDte + @Lcounter
    GROUP BY 
        Year(ACD.WorkDte), ACD.LOB

    SET @Lcounter = @Lcounter + 1
END 
GO
```

Comment: You should be able to write this without using a loop at all, but I need more information about the data and schema to provide an example. Without that information, what you have is confusing: using the name "RptType" for a day counter, for example, especially when "month" is set as the level.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you need a "table" of some kind with one record representing each iteration in your loop. If all else fails, you can do this by inserting one record into a temp table in your loop. Once you have this table, you can write a query that JOINs it again your original data set, such that you don't need your current loop at all. All the data is retrieved as part of a single query. In this case, you'll also need to update the GROUP BY expression, to keep the group aggregate functions limited to data matching individual records from your new table.

I'd provide an example, but I'd need some sample data, and some of what's in your current query is confusing: why is a field that increments days named `RptType`, and if you are incrementing days, why is the `Level` field have a value of `Month`?

If that's too complicated for you, you can take your existing query and just insert the results from each iteration into a temp table, and then select that temp table at the end... though this is **far** from the preferred way to work with a database.